# Diagonal shape buttons with overlapping corners

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to know how I can achieve this with css or by just creating image slices. See the attached image, the buttons are diagonal and if I slice one button the corner of it overlaps the other button. I'm not sure how I can achieve this. Can someone please advise. I need to do achieve this so it is compatible with IE 8.

Thank you![image]

Comment: Couldn't you add a margin between the buttons in your css?

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS

Comment: Use pseudo elements to create the angles and then pull the following buttons using the width of the pseudo element using the sibling selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic example.

I use `transform:skew(30deg);`, and the `:after` pseudo element.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVnst/2/)

**HTML - pretty simple**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    background-color:blue;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform:skew(30deg);
    -moz-transform:skew(30deg);
    -o-transform:skew(30deg);
    transform:skew(30deg);
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    height:100%;
    width:2px;
    position:relative;
    left:110px;
    background:black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See this snippet here. It explains in detail what I think you are trying to achieve. http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Civzw

Answer (score 2):

Or without skew and using pseudo-elements at both ends.

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/liuCy)

```
div {
  height:50px;
  width:125px;
  background:red;
  position:relative;
}

div:after {
  position:absolute;
  right:-50px;
  content:"";
  border-top:25px solid transparent;  
  border-right:25px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:25px solid blue; /* change as required */
  border-left:25px solid blue; /* change as required */
}

div:before {
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  left:-50px;
  border-top:25px solid green; /* change as required */
  border-right:25px solid green; /* change as required */
  border-bottom:25px solid transparent;
  border-left:25px solid transparent;
}
```